# HTML structure isn't the same as I wrote it

Tags: html, structure

I've never seen this behaviour before, but I got a `<p>` with some "sub-divs" like this:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, Stet 
  <div href="#" class="l-definition" data-label="test">Chromium
    <div class='definition'>Test</div>
  </div> 
  kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</p>
```

When I open up my webpage then, it "splits up" my code into this:
[image: Problem]
It closes the `<p>` too early and creates a `<p></p>` at the end.
Does anyone know, why this problem occurs?

Answer (score -1):

p tag is a block level element, and is (supposed to be) used for displaying text, it won't allow other block level elements inside it, but only inline ones like span and strong